# Can't get JSOUP to keep cookies

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

I'm attempting to make an application to login to a website and then grab the requested data. Currently, I'm just focusing on the login portion and getting the source of the page I require.

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/communicator.jsp?fun=buslogin&memberID=user&pin=password")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Document doc = res.parse();
        String sessionId = res.cookie("JSESSIONID");

        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/communicator.jsp?fun=buslogin&memberID=username&pin=password")
                .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId)
                .post();

        Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/accounts.jsp")
                .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionId)
                .post();

        String htmlString = document2.toString();
        System.out.println(htmlString);



    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nAn exception occurred.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

'user' and 'password' in the URL are referring to my user and pass used to login through the URL.

The output I receive when setting the println statement to 'document2' is:

```
Internet banking has logged out as it has not been used for 10 minutes.
You will be redirected 
<br>to the log-in page, but if no activity occurs in a few seconds, 
please click <a href="ebank.jsp" target="_top">here</a>.
```

This should be outputting the source of the accounts.jsp page, however it's outputting as if it wasn't logged in.

If I set the println statement to 'document' I get the full source of the welcome page. Since I get an output only available after logging in, I can tell that this part is successful. This makes be believe that the JSESSIONID cookie isn't carrying over to the 'document2' section.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a thought : is the JSESSIONID cookie the only one that you need? Might there be others that you're not picking up?

Comment: Just added the other SCSESSIONID, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Use your browser's develpoer tools to see all the data that the browser is sending to the server. There's probably more then just cookies.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of selecting "some" cookies to send to the server, I would suggest that you send the entire `cookies` as a whole.

Secondly, if the above does not work, make sure to keep adding the cookies you receive from each response and pass those on to the next request.

So, it would be like this:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/communicator.jsp?fun=buslogin&memberID=user&pin=password")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();

Document doc = res.parse();
// String sessionId = res.cookie("JSESSIONID");
HashMap<String, String> cookies = res.cookies(); //This hashmap will contain your cookies

Connection.Response res1 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/communicator.jsp?fun=buslogin&memberID=username&pin=password")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .post();

cookies.addAll(res1.cookies); // keep adding the cookies

Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.accessweb.co.nz/south/accounts.jsp")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .post();

String htmlString = res2.parse().toString();
System.out.println(htmlString);
```

If the above still does not work, I suggest you examine closely what kind of parameters are sent when you normally login to your bank from desktop browser, this can be done using the network tab of the developer tool of your browser.

Comment: Just attempted this. Couldn't manage to get it to work; even after adding the JSESSIONID and SCSESSIONID cookies manually. Appreciate the help though!